# Add Aliases to Bash Terminal from inside of VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to add aliases to the bash terminal when using it from within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Has Noone answered for Linux systems? Curious...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer here
https://gist.github.com/wzup/36b5159d8c580b827384

Take as an inspiration

```
# create a file C:\Users\[user]\.bashrc
# add this content
# add your onw aliases or changes these ones as you like
# to make a dot (.bashrs) file in windows, create a file ".bashrs." (without extention) and save. windows will save it as ".bashrc"

alias ls='ls -alh'
alias cdnginx='cd /c/nginx && ls'
alias cdmcga='cd /c/Users/[user]/sbox/node/mcga && ls'
alias cdfood9='cd /c/Users/[user]/sbox/node/food9 && ls'
alias cdmysql='cd /c/nginx/mysql/bin && ls'
alias cdsbox='cd /c/Users/[user]/sbox && ls'
alias cdangular='cd /c/Users/[user]/sbox/angularjs && ls'
alias cdmongobin='cd "/c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.0/bin" && ls'
alias cdmongodata='cd /c/mongodb/data/db && ls'
alias sbrc='cd ~ && source .bashrc'
alias mydocs='cd ~/Documents'
```

Comment: At least "I found" this proper way to do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am using MAC with zsh, and is same place (your user folder) and the file has the name .zshrc

For see the hidden files in MAC: Cmd + shift + .

> alias ball="npm run build-all"