# Git bash will not resolve "sam" command

Tags: git-bash, aws-sam-cli

I am using Win10 latest. After installing AWS-SAM-CLI and testing the installation with:

```
sam --version
```

I get the message

> bash: sam: command not found

however, when I use Powershell, cmd or ConEmu they can all resolve "sam".

the path is "e/Program Files/Amazon/AWSSAMCLI/bin"
but other commands like "yarn" work fine which is also installed at "e/Program Files/..."

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can use `alias sam="sam.cmd"` if it works in normal cmd. Now `sam --version` should work.

Comment: it can also be set to create the alias on terminal open, like with `echo 'alias sam="sam.cmd"' >> ~/.bashrc` for e.g. ; some more thoughts on that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/602872/how-do-i-modify-my-git-bash-profile-in-windows?newreg=11a9bb92102040fc83225f509c48b46f)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
sam.cmd --version
```

The windows version of the SAM CLI does not have a direct executable binary. It is instead a .cmd script that echos your options to the python executable.

```
@rem
@echo off

setlocal

"%~dp0/../runtime/python.exe" -m samcli %*
```

I haven't figured out how to make it work with

```
sam --version
```

My assumption is that powershell and command prompt see .cmd as an executable not requiring an extension where git bash does not.

Comment: You can make it work without the .cmd extension by adding an alias in your .bashrc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50391166/1429439

Comment: The fact that this is not in docs for installation is annoying

Comment: Thanks @C.M. I literally just did `alias sam='sam.cmd'`, and it's working great. :)

Answer (score 26):

Here is how I got it work with an alias.
`alias sam="/c/Program\ Files/Amazon/AWSSAMCLI/bin/sam.cmd"`

Comment: While the alias worked when invoking sam straight from the command line it wouldn't work in scripts. After following the above step to make them work in scripts use 'sam.cmd' instead of 'sam'

Comment: where are you adding the alias?  in vs code or somewhere else?

Comment: Just run this in the cli (i.e. git bash)

Answer (score 8):

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc  # or favorite editor
```

Add:

```
alias sam='sam.cmd'
```

Then:

```
$ source ./.bashrc # can use '. ./.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

While the alias worked when invoking `sam` straight from the command line it wouldn't work in scripts that I was using.

To fix this for both instances I found that I needed to add a shell
script equivalent of the installed `.cmd` script, named `sam`, in the same folder as it, typically
`C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

"$basedir/../runtime/python.exe" -m samcli "$@"
ret=$?
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the SAM CLI. You can do this by running the following commands:

> ```
> pip uninstall aws-sam-cli
> pip install aws-sam-cli
> ```

2. Check the version of Python you're using. The SAM CLI requires Python 3.6 or later. You can check your Python version by running the command python --version. If you're using an earlier version of Python, you'll need to upgrade to a later version.