# VS Code on macOS python command not found

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio

When I try to run some python code on Visual Studio Code terminal gives me the error:

```
[Running] python -u "...project path..."
/bin/sh: python: command not found
```

On my mac the command to run python is python3,
for example:

```
python3 --version
```

I tried writing in bash_profile

```
alias python='python3'
```

but it did not work.

Is there any way to tell VS Code to use `python3 -u`  instead of `python`

Comment: You can probably open the command pallet and search for "Python Select Interpreter" then pick one you like :-)

Comment: Even putting in "python:defaunt interpreter path" the correct path keeps telling me python command not found because the correct command would be python3 but I absolutely didn't understand how to change this thing

Comment: Why not put the path to python3 in?

Comment: @Alex does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369614/add-aliases-to-bash-terminal-from-inside-of-vsc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Aliases to Bash Terminal from inside of VSC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369614/add-aliases-to-bash-terminal-from-inside-of-vsc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode running Python 2 instead of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299927/vscode-running-python-2-instead-of-3)

Answer (score 2):

After quite a bit of searching I found the problem, it was in the settings.json file of the Code Runner extension, changing Code-runner: Executor Map from settings and replacing `python -u` with `python3 -u` fixed the problem.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs83c.png)

[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um6Eg.png)